# Handling lots of objects

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

First, I am an objective-c newbie. Just thought I would get that out of the way ;)

I am trying to handle objects but I'm a bit confused about the best way to go around doing so. Let me put this into a bit of context:

I have a preference area where a user can add a new Foo to the app. Once the input fields are validated it should spawn a new object of type Foo (according to my Foo class). The user could have anywhere from 1 to 100 of these in the app. What is the best way of keeping track of all of these? How can I create them in the code and keep track of them?

I bet that made no sense, but I have tried to explain it the best I can. Please feel free to ask for more details.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends somewhat on what you want to do with them.  To just keep them in RAM, you can store pointers to those objects in an NSArray (or NSMutableArray), or if you need to be able to find them with a key use an NSDictionary (or NSMutableDictionary).  To save them so that they persist even after your app exits so you can load them again next time you can them write them to a file ([plist, sqllite, coredata, ...](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html)).

Comment: Ah, that sounds perfect, thanks. I will give this a shot a bit later. Do the object pointers need to be unique when storing them in an dictionary or can I just resuse code with the same pointers (after releasing them) like this [someDictionary setObject:someObject forKey:userInputName];

Comment: In an [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html) keys must be unique.  BTW you can look at the doc for any class like NSxxxxx by googling "NSxxxxx class reference".

Comment: Yeah, the key would be unique as I would check if was already used (NSString from an NSTextField), but I mean the pointer for the object "someObject", can that be reused once released or will the dictionary require it to be unique also?

Comment: The general object-oriented concept you're looking for is "collection classes" - objects that act as containers for other objects. There are different containers best for different purposes. For Cocoa, see this guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Collection.html

Comment: prgrmr, @derpking: Better than Googling it, you can use Apple's own search: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=NSArray Instructions on adding a shortcut to Chrome or OmniWeb: http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2011-03-06/chrome-omniweb-adc-searches

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I thought you said *lots*. :-)  I was already planning an explanation on the *flyweight pattern* when I read 'up to 100'. You can just put these in [an array](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#nsarray).

Comment: Well 100 would be a lot for a newbie like me! ;)